# how to wait for the end a thread before going any further

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http

I'm working on an Android project and i'm going through a problem with the thread i'm doing an HTTP request.

I'm trying to get a token, refresh token ... from an API.

Here is the code :

```
public class OAuthHelper {

    static TokenModel tokenObj;
    final static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public static TokenModel getTokens(final RequestModel request) throws InterruptedException{
        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    try
                    {
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://api.listopresto.com/oauth/token");
                         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                         if (request.getType() == "password"){
                             Log.i("infos", "password");
                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "antoine"));
                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "toto"));
                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "knocka.a@gmail.com"));
                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "toto"));                             
                         }
                         else{
                             Log.i("infos", "refresh_token");
                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "refresh_token"));
                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "antoine"));
                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "toto"));
                             nameValuePairs.add(new Bas icNameValuePair("refresh_token", request.getRefreshToken()));
                         }
                         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                        String s = reader.readLine();
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        tokenObj = gson.fromJson(s, new TypeToken<TokenModel>(){}.getType());
                        latch.countDown();

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        Log.i("infos", "first");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.i("infos", "second");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.i("infos", "third");
                }
            }
    };
    thread.start();
    latch.await();
    return (tokenObj);
    }
}
```

When i'm doing a request fron a user and password there is no problem. i get the right object with the tokens ... But when i'm doing the second one, it seems that i return tokenObj before the end of my thread. i thaught that i fixed this problem by using the latch.await() but i'm still having the problem.

I'm looking for a solution to wait the end of the thread before returning tokenObj.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Don't use plain java `Thread` class, switch to `AsyncTask`, you will do your OAuth network job inside doInBackground and then after its done, you will do all UI updates inside onPostExecute.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to wait for your thread to finish to return your token. Doing so will lock your UI thread and if the web request takes more than a few seconds, your user will see a message from Android telling them that your app is not responding, suggesting them to force close it.


What you want to do is change your code to make use of `AsyncTask`. Learn more at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html